# how to list, files from a specified folder in the internal directory of android device

Tags: java, javascript, android

**i need to display files from a specified folder in the directory**
*example the root path is Directory:/sdcard/GDM/*
how can i list the files from this folder.

Answer (score 0):

The `File` class provides you with a `list()` method:

> Returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the
>   directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this abstract pathname
>   does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise
>   an array of strings is returned, one for each file or directory in the
>   directory. Names denoting the directory itself and the directory's
>   parent directory are not included in the result. Each string is a file
>   name rather than a complete path.
>
> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

So, the code will be something like:

```
File root = new File("/sdcard/GDM");
String[] files = root.list();  
if( files != null ){
 // do something
}
```

**Update(s):**
To get the size of the file, you will need the `length()` method. This will return the size in bytes. If you want to get it in MBs, you will need to divide it by `1024*1024`

```
File f = new File("/path/to/some/file");
double sizeInMb = f.length() / (1024*1024);
```

Comment: how can i show the size of the file, while listing. and also i want to open the file on clicking. will u help me

Comment: @visanthvichu Please check the update. Opening the file on click depends on how you show the files to the users. Is it in a list?

Answer (score 0):

To get list of files from your sdcard,

```
List<File> listFilesRoot = getFilesFromRoot(new File("YOUR PATH"));


private List<File> getFilesFromRoot(File parentDir) {
        ArrayList<File> listFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (!file.isDirectory())  {
                    listFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
        return listFiles;
    }
```